# mIRC If Timer X is running

Tags: irc, mirc

Im looking to make an if statement that will check if a timer is running!

Ex

```
on *:text:*ABC*:#: { 
  if timerX is running { msg $chan Working! }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
on *:TEXT:*ABC*:#:{
  if ($timer("name").secs) { msg $chan working }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to use property ".secs", not if you wanted to check ONLY if the timer is running

by the way, i would not recommend to use wildcards on "on text" matches, since it can match everything.

```
on $*:text:/^!timercheck\s(.+\s)/:#:{ if ($timer($regml(1))) { code here for working} else { code here for not working } }
```

or you can use $iif

```
on $*:text:/^!timercheck\s(.+\s)\s/:#:{
msg $chan $+($nick,:) Timer $qt($regml(1)) is $iif(!$timer($regml(1)),not) running
}
```

as example

^ = the first thing in line
\s = space after the command
(.+\s) = first word after the space